# OpenCV: Remap axis direction?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

When I study the CV2.remap() function, the result sometime does not looks like same as my expectation.

I am very confused about this function, perhaps it related to matrix dot and remap mechanism, but I cannot figure it out from the CV2 [manual](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/da0/tutorial_remap.html).

Source code in python 3.x:

```
def test_image_remap(self):
    image218time52 = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\mac\\sample\\cvaxis.png")
    x_size = 52
    y_size = 218
    u = np.zeros((x_size, y_size), dtype=np.float32)(52, 218)#u.shape = (52, 218)
    v = np.zeros((x_size, y_size), dtype=np.float32)         #v.shape = (52, 218)
    ybase, xbase = np.mgrid[:image218time52.shape[0], :image218time52.shape[1]]
    map1 = (xbase + u).astype(np.float32) #map1.shape = (52, 218)
    map2 = (ybase + v).astype(np.float32) #map2.shape = (52, 218)
    warped = cv2.remap(image218time52, map1, map2, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

    cv2.imshow('warped_image.png', warped)
    cv2.imwrite(".//result.png", warped)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

[image: cvaxis.png]

This is the source file cvaxis.png, it is 218 by 52 (w, h), however in the source code it defines x_size = 52 and y_size = 280 and the map1 shape is (52,218).

I tried to change it to x_size = 218, y_size = 52 and the code does not run.

Why the CV2.remap() asking its map1 shape is (52,218) when source picture is (218,52)?

Thank you.

Comment: did you confuse width and height? "x_size" being 52 sounds wrong. OpenCV doesn't take numpy shapes, it takes `(width, height)` tuples, if it asks for that. the maps' shapes have to match, so `(height, width)` (single channel)

Comment: Thank you Christoph, I think you are right. The OpenCV has 2 features which not mention in their manual: (1). It does not take Numpy shapes(however it can compile and run), it takes (width, height) tuples; (2). The OpenCV.remap() desire input should be square shape. So, if anyone using Numpy or other API, can output the image after rotation without losing any data. That is my solution, later I change it to a square, and process with the cv2.remap(source, map1, map2, interpolation) and give a rotation to the output.